# How to generate multiple promises from a list returned from a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm quite new to promises and struggle to understand this: I have a promise, which returns a list of values. How can I start a new promise from each of these values?

Here is some example code that I try to get working:

```
var generateList = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        var color = ["black", "white"];
        resolve(color);
    }
);

var showColor = function (color) {
    console.log("Color: " + color);
};

function handleList(list){
    var somePromises = [];
    somePromises[0] = Promise.resolve(list[0]);
    somePromises[1] = Promise.resolve(list[1]);
    // somePromises = [promise0, promise1];
    // var somePromises = list.map(Promise.resolve);
    return somePromises;
}

var startPromises = function () {
    generateList.then(handleList).then(showColor);
};

startPromises();
```

I expect `showColor` to be called twice, printing both colors in their own line. How can I achieve this? I tried to use `Promise.all`, but couldn't make it work.

---

## Edit

I might have oversimplified my question. I want to call a new (always the same chain) of Promises on each of the list elements.

```
var makeCapital = function (word){
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        resolve(word.toUpperCase());
    });
};
```

And extend my chain like this:

```
var startPromises = function () {
    generateList.then(handleList).then(makeCapital).then(showColor);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of `handleList`? Do you realise that it does nothing useful here, and the `Promise.resolve` call is just an example of some actual asynchronous operation?

Comment: Btw, `var generateList = Promise.resolve(["black", "white"]);`. Much simpler :-)

Comment: @Bergi I removed a few lines to keep the example simpler. The `handleList` was just an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: No, just drop the `handleList` then. You need to put the `makeCapital` and `showColor` calls in some kind of loop, there's no way around that. Promise chains do not magically handle arrays for you.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Putting a `handleList` before them in the chain cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `Promise.all`.

No, `makeCapital` and `showColor` and will be called only once when they are put only once as a `then` callback, in your `generateList.….then(makeCapital).then(showColor)` chain. There is no way to write a `.then(handleList)` that changes this.

You need to call them in that loop inside your `handleList` function - either as

```
generateList.then(function makeCapitalList(list) {
    var somePromises = list.map(makeCapital);
    return Promise.all(somePromises);
}).then(function showColorList(colors) {
    colors.forEach(showColor); // or use `map` if they return something sensible
                               // and also `Promise.all` again if they return promises
    console.log("all done.");
});
```

or with the `showColor` handler on each of the individual promises that are created in the loop:

```
generateList.then(function handleList(list) {
    var somePromises = list.map(color => {
        var somePromise = makeCapital(color).then(showColor);
        return somePromise;
    });
    return Promise.all(somePromises);
}).then(() => {
    console.log("all done.");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should return `Promise.all(somePromises);`
- Loop for every color in `listOfColors` that was returned by function `handleList`:

```js
var generateList = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        var color = ["black", "white"];
        resolve(color);
    }
);

var showColor = function (color) {
    console.log("Color: " + color);
};

function handleList(list){
    var somePromises = [
      Promise.resolve(list[0]),
      Promise.resolve(list[1])
    ];
    
    return Promise.all(somePromises);
}

var startPromises = function () {
    generateList.then(handleList).then(function(listOfColors) {
      // This forEach will call the function showColor twice.
      listOfColors.forEach(c => showColor(c)); 
    });
};

startPromises();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I might oversimplified my example. Can I create a new promise for each of the elements in the list? Together with the same chain of `then(...)` on each promise.